# getting new data per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

my data looks like this:

```
+--------+-----------+---------+
| doctor | datefield | patient |
+--------+-----------+---------+
| A      | 1/1/2011  | ABC123  |
| A      | 1/20/2011 | AAA123  |
| A      | 1/21/2011 | AAA123  |
|        |           |         |
| A      | 2/1/2011  | ABC123  |
| A      | 2/10/2011 | BBBYYY  |
|        |           |         |
| B      | 1/1/2011  | ABC123  |
| B      | 1/20/2011 | AXA435  |
| B      | 1/21/2011 | AAA123  |
|        |           |         |
| B      | 2/1/2011  | ABC123  |
| B      | 2/10/2011 | BBBYYY  |
+--------+-----------+---------+
```

I want to calculate the new patients per doctor `as compared to the entire date range for that specific doctor`.

let's assume **january 2011** was the first month.

**logic:**

> 1. doctor A had 2 new patients for january 2011
> 2. doctor A had 1 new patient for feb 2011
> 3. doctor B had 3 new patients for January 2011
> 4. doctor B had 1 new patient for feb 2011

here's the result that i would like:

```
+--------+-------+------+----------------+
| doctor | month | year | # new patients |
+--------+-------+------+----------------+
| A      |     1 | 2011 |              2 |
| A      |     2 | 2011 |              1 |
| B      |     1 | 2011 |              3 |
| B      |     2 | 2011 |              1 |
+--------+-------+------+----------------+
```

can you please help me to get started?

Comment: How do you know which patients are new ones?

Comment: the way to know is to compare with the previous month

Comment: What if a patient came in two months ago?

Comment: What I'm getting at is are you comparing all of the patients that a doctor has ever seen before, or only the patients that a doctor saw during the last month?

Comment: @jim thank you very much for this. i needed to clarify that it's new patient in the ENTIRE DATE RANGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple to get the total number of patients for a month:

```
SELECT Doctor, YEAR(datef) AS yr, MONTH(datef) AS mnth, COUNT(patient) AS totPatients FROM ##doctors
GROUP BY Doctor, YEAR(datef), MONTH(datef)

Doctor  yr      mnth    totPatients
A       2011    1       3
A       2011    2       2
B       2011    1       3
B       2011    2       2
```

But getting the number of new patients is slightly more complex. For this, we need to get the first visit of each patient. This can be done with:

```
SELECT doctor, patient, MIN(MONTH(datef)) AS Mnth, MIN(YEAR(datef)) AS Yr FROM ##doctors GROUP BY doctor, patient
```

Then, by combining the two, we get the desired result:

```
WITH fstVisit AS (
    SELECT doctor, patient, min(month(datef)) AS Mnth, min(year(datef)) AS Yr FROM ##doctors GROUP BY doctor, patient
    )
    SELECT Doctor,  yr, mnth, COUNT(patient) AS totPatients FROM fstVisit
    GROUP BY Doctor, yr, mnth

Doctor  yr      mnth    totPatients
A       2011    1       2
A       2011    2       1
B       2011    1       3
B       2011    2       1
```

Comment: i tried to validate one of the datapoints like this: select COUNT(distinct patient_id)
from F_ACCESSION_DAILY
where 
REQUESTOR_NPI='1971403'
and DATEPART(yyyy,RECEIVED_DATE)=2011
and DATEPART(mm,RECEIVED_DATE) =10
and PATIENT_ID not in

(select distinct PATIENT_ID from F_ACCESSION_DAILY where RECEIVED_DATE<'20111001' and requestor_npi='1971403')

Comment: would you say that this is a fair validation? im not getting expected results.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, could you rephrase?

Answer (score 2):

Just need to break it out into a couple steps:

- Determine which month was the first month for a given patient and doctor (i.e. `select doctor, patient, min(month) from mytable group by doctor, patient`)
- Count the number of new patients by grouping the previous result by doctor and month

Should be able to do this with either a subquery or a temp table/table variable, whichever way you prefer.

EDIT:
The query I'd write would probably look something like:

```
select doctor, year, month, count(1) [num_new]
from
(
    select doctor
           ,patient
           ,datepart(mm, min(datefield)) [month]
           ,datepart(yyyy, min(datefield)) [year]
    from mytable
    group by doctor, patient
) sub
group by doctor, year, month
```

Comment: thanks so much, joe. im not sure i understand? this is what i think you said: ;with ctemain as (select doctor, patient, min(month) from mytable group by doctor, patient) select * from ctemain group by doctor,month ??

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the "with" syntax personally, but I believe that's exactly right. I've edited the answer to show how I'd do it.

Comment: i am getting this joe, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group' for the second GROUP BY

Comment: Ok, it should work now. Two things were wrong - the 'mm' and 'yyyy' should not have been in quotes - and the subquery needed an alias. That's what happens when I write SQL without testing it.

Comment: this does not work . tried to validate like this 

select COUNT(distinct patient_id)
from F_ACCESSION_DAILY
where 
REQUESTOR_NPI='17009498'
and DATEPART(yyyy,RECEIVED_DATE)=2012
and DATEPART(mm,RECEIVED_DATE) =4



and PATIENT_ID not in
(select distinct PATIENT_ID 
from F_ACCESSION_DAILY 
where RECEIVED_DATE<'20120401' and REQUESTOR_NPI='17009498' )
 and got 0 results, whereas your query returns like 40

Comment: Don't know about your true underlying data structure, but with the example data you provided, this query does give the results that you are expecting. Try taking a single example and see where it goes wrong - for example, find patient 12345, run them through your main query without the "not in" part, then through your subquery, then through my subquery, then finally just a raw data dump for that patient, and find out everything you can about that one patient. That should tell you which query is good.

Answer (score 2):

corrected syntax on Joe's answer

```
select doctor, year, month, count(patient) [num_new]
from (select doctor, patient, min(MONTH([datefield])) [month], min(YEAR([datefield]))  [year]
    from [dbo].[test_aakruti]
    group by doctor, patient) as table1
group by doctor, [year], [month]
```

Comment: That won't work, since you're taking the min month and the min year, so if they were in Jan 2012 and Feb 2011, it would return Jan 2011. I'm working on fixing it - not sure why SQL doesn't like it, but it shouldn't be too difficult to change.